# Listview is not highlighting items when clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a listview in my c# application and items are added into the listview like this:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var name = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn1);
                var away = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn2);
                var until = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn3);
                var debt = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn4);
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(until.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(name.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(away.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(until.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(debt.ToString());
                lstDates.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

but whenever I try to click on one of the items in the listview it doesn't highlight it blue. I have tried adding this but this also does not work:

```
        private void lstDates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

If someone could please help it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: ListView must be created with flags, to have visible "selection"

Comment: @JacekCz Hi, I just added these two lines after the while loop: lstDates.Visible = true;
lstDates.HideSelection = false; - it is still not working, any ideas?